# Iteratively create subclass and store objects as class attribute

Tags: python, class, subclass

I have a class that does some complex calculation and generates some result `MyClass.myresults`.

`MyClass.myresults` is actually a class itself with different attributes (e.g. `MyClass.myresults.mydf1`, `MyClass.myresults.mydf2`.

Now, I need to run `MyClass` iteratively following a list of scenarios(`scenarios=[1,2,[2,4], 5]`.

This happens with a simple loop:

```
    for iter in scenarios:
        iter = [iter] if isinstance(iter, int) else iter
        myclass = MyClass() #Initialize MyClass
        myclass.DoStuff(someInput) #Do stuff and get results
        results.StoreScenario(myclass.myresults, iter)
```

and at the end of each iteration store `MyClass.myresults`.

I would like to create a separate class (`Results`) that at each iteration creates a subclass `scenario_1, scenario_2, scenario_2_4` and stores within it `MyClass.myresults`.

```
class Results:
    # no initialization, is an empty container to which I would like to add attributes iteratively
    class StoreScenario:
        def __init__(self, myresults, iter):
            self.'scenario_'.join(str(iter)) = myresults #just a guess, I am assuming this is wrong
```

Suggestions on different approaches are more than welcome, I am quite new to classes and I am not sure if this is an acceptable approach or if I am doing something awful (clunky, memory inefficient, or else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it using [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

```
class Results:

    def __init__(self):
        self.scenario_results= type('ScenarioResults', (), {}) # create an empty object


    def store_scenario(self, data, scenarios):
        scenario_key = 'scenario_' + '_'.join(str(x) for x in scenarios)
        setattr(self.simulation_results, scenario_key, 
                subclass_store_scenario(data))

class subclass_store_scenario:
    def __init__(self, data):

        self.some_stuff = data.result1.__dict__
        self.other_stuff = data.result2.__dict__
```

This allows me to call things like:

```
results.scenario_results.scenario_1.some_stuff.something
results.scenario_results.scenario_1.some_stuff.something_else
```

This is necessary for me as I need to compute other measures, summary or scenario-specific, which I can then iteratively assign using again `setattr`:

```
    def construct_measures(self, some_data, configuration):
        for scenario in self.scenario_results: 
            #scenario is a reference to the self.scenario_results class. 
            #we can simply add attributes to it
            setattr(scenario , 'some_measure',
                    self.computeSomething(
                            some_data.input1, some_data.input2))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two problems of using this approach, The first one is, **Result** class (separate class) only stores modified values of your class **MyClass**, I mean, they should be the same class.

The second problem is **memory efficiency**, you create the same object twice for storing actual values and modified values at each iteration.

The suggested approach is using a **hashmap** or a **dictionary** in python. Using **dictionary** you are able to store copies of modified object very efficient and there's no need to create another class.

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    # some attributes ...
    self.scenarios_result = {}
```

---

```
superObject = MyClass()

for iter in scenarios:

    iter = [iter] if isinstance(iter, int) else iter

    myclass = MyClass() #Initialize MyClass
    myclass.DoStuff(someInput) #Do stuff and get results

    # results.StoreScenario(myclass.myresults, iter)

    superObject.scenarios_result[iter] = myclass
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. How do I then call the attributes of each stored class object? Using your example, calling: `superObject.scenarios_result[iter]` would return a class object. How do I call, for example: `superObject.scenarios_result[iter].MyAttribute`?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, for accessing your class attributes (copied object), you indexing the dictionary using the key (iter for this example).